# tf::TransformListener lookupTransform time error

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to listen to a transform using a tf::TransformListener, but I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1320937607.066118093]: Exception thrown while processing service call: 
Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1320937602.045533235, 
but only time 1320937602.055791850 is in the buffer, 
when looking up transform from frame [/base_link] to frame [/mid_obj_preg_0]
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error: if you look at the 2 time stamps, they're very close, and I initialized my tf_listener with a big buffer of 60seconds.

I also ran the view frames, and you can see that there's a transform from /base_link to /mid_obj_preg_0.
[image: Frames]

The transforms from /camera_rgb_optical_frame to /mid_obj_preg_0 are published by the same tf::TransformBroadcaster. Should I be using one broadcaster per transform?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11884/tf::transformlistener-lookuptransform-time-error/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It does not look like you are not doing anything wrong on the publishing side.

It looks like your problem is that you have only received one message so far from the publisher.  (That message is unique to a single message in the buffer.)  This is a common startup issue.  Although you initialized the TransformListener with a 60 second buffer it has not had time to build up a history as it has only received one message concerning the link mentioned.  Once your TransformListener has been listening for 60 seconds then it will have filled up it's buffer.

If you make your program robust to exceptions and either retry or just toss the data and wait for new data such that the buffer has had time to fill, I expect you'll find it starts working.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-11-10**:
Hi Tully, Thanks for your answer. I ended up broadcasting my transforms and listening for it until I was able to read it.